# Using ES2016 (ES7) Can I replace underscore's pick method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

The one thing I haven't figured out how to do using new ES syntax is create an object that is a subset of another *based on declared included values*.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
//input
let user = {
  id: 123,
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar',
  password: 'hunter2'
};

//output
let safeUser = {
  id: user.id,
  foo: user.foo,
  bar: user.bar
}

//NOT this (I don't want to declare excluded vals)
let {password, ...safeUser} = user;
```

If it's not possible, anyone know if something is in the works? I looked on esdiscuss & babel but nothing turned up.

Comment: So you want to go from what's in `user` to what's in `safeUser`? That is, you want to include everything but (in this case) `password`?

Comment: yep! but without excluding `password`.

Comment: wait – so, if you don't want to exclude `password`, what are you trying to do? What do you want in the final object that's different from the other two?

Comment: I don't want to *exclude* `password`, I want to declaratively *include* everything else. It's the difference between `_.pick()` and `_.omit()`

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this of you, but could you write out an equivalent `_.pick` expression for me, please?

Comment: `_.pick(user, 'id', 'foo', 'bar')`

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#pick